# Outputting CRUD data based on an sql table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, crud, kendo-ui

I'm trying to get to grips with Kendo UI, one thing they do is read from a datasource, the datasource being this: http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Products

There's also one for updating (demos.kendoui.com/service/Update), destroy and create.

Is there a way I can quickly automate the creation of these URLs on an asp.net mvc server for a given database?

I'm very new to CRUD operations so hopefully I'm asking the right questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to post this question on the Telerik Kendo UI forum itself.

I posted a related question and it was crystal clear explained and aswered within hours by the Telerik crew.

Good luck on this amazing framework! I love it!